# I can't do mysql php artisan migrations in my docker compose. Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I'm currently developing a laravel-vue-mysql environment with docker compose.

I took as guide these articles [link](https://developpaper.com/building-the-development-environment-of-laravel-and-vue-project-with-docker/) [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-laravel-nginx-y-mysql-con-docker-compose-es)

My docker compose is working fine the web and app services are working good and its deploy as it should. But i can't configure my db. 
I'm try executing `docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate` but I have  SQLSTATE no such file or directory exception, I'm been stuck for 3 days in this.

I've read all comments about this problem but could get solution. I have given all privileges to root user in my db. I have tried changing my dbhost with my container ip or container db name, I have tried changing database.php host for my db name too but it didn't work either.

I think my error could be in my `"unix_socket' => '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',"`

I'd like to clarify this route i got it through log in my docker mysql service and put a command in my db. I don't know if i have to put mysql.lock local route
which is **/tmp/mysql.sock**

Or it could be my database_url route, I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Need some help.

I want to create the data tables in my mysql docker service

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

  # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    container_name: app      
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    container_name: web      
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80

# The Database
  database:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: db.dockerfile
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db  
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=root"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

app.dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Update packages
RUN apt-get update

# Install PHP and composer dependencies
RUN apt-get install -qq git curl libmcrypt-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev libbz2-dev

# Clear out the local repository of retrieved package files
# RUN apt-get clean

# Install needed extensions
# Here you can install any other extension that you need during the test and deployment process
RUN apt-get -y install libzip-dev
RUN pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3 
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
RUN apt-get clean; docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip gd pcntl opcache bcmath


# Installs Composer to easily manage your PHP dependencies.
RUN curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install Node
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg &&\
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - &&\
    apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nodejs &&\
    npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org --global &&\
    npm install --global gulp-cli

CMD php-fpm
```

db.dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:5.7

# Setup the custom configuration
ADD my.cnf /mysql/mysql.conf.d/my.cnf
```

web.dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.10

ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /var/www
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@database:33061/homestead
```

vhost.config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

This is my .cnf

```
    [mysqld]
    # Accept connections from any IP address
    general_log = 1
    general_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/general.log
    bind-address                = 0.0.0.0
    socket= /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    #skip-grant-tables

This is my app/config/database.php 

     'mysql' => [
            'driver'=>'mysql',
            'url'=>env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host'=>env('DB_HOST','database'),
            'port'=>env('DB_PORT','3306'),
            'database'=>env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'=>env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'=>env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket'=>'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
            'charset'=>'utf8mb4',
            'collation'=>'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'=>'',
            'prefix_indexes'=>true,
            'strict'=>true,
            'engine'=> null,
            'options'=> extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA =>env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

When i try to migrate the mysql database it's return me this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")
      /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory")
      /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27

  3   PDO::__construct("mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;dbname=homestead", "root", "secret", [])
      /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27

  4   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection::__construct("mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;dbname=homestead", "root", "secret", [])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:67

  5   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createPdoConnection("mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;dbname=homestead", "root", "secret", [])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:46

  6   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createConnection("mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;dbname=homestead", [])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php:24

  7   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector::connect()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:182

  8   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::Illuminate\Database\Connectors\{closure}()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:924

  9   call_user_func(Object(Closure))
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:924

  10  Illuminate\Database\Connection::getPdo()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:959

  11  Illuminate\Database\Connection::getReadPdo()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:404

  12  Illuminate\Database\Connection::getPdoForSelect()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:330

  13  Illuminate\Database\Connection::Illuminate\Database\{closure}("select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:662

  14  Illuminate\Database\Connection::runQueryCallback("select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'", Object(Closure))
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:629

  15  Illuminate\Database\Connection::run("select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'", Object(Closure))
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:338

  16  Illuminate\Database\Connection::select("select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.php:18

  17  Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::hasTable("migrations")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php:169

  18  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository::repositoryExists()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:590

  19  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::repositoryExists()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:91

  20  Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand::prepareDatabase()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:63

  21  Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand::handle()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:32

  22  call_user_func_array([])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:32

  23  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php:36

  24  Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:90

  25  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Closure))
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:34

  26  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:590

  27  Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:134

  28  Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255

  29  Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:121

  30  Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1001

  31  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:271

  32  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:147

  33  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:93

  34  Illuminate\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:131

  35  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      /var/www/artisan:37
```

Comment: Your values in `.env` are conflicting. I'm not sure of which will take priority, but I'd suggest making port number, host name, etc all match up.

Comment: What would you change?

Comment: Change it so they aren't conflicting. Your URL has no password, but DB_PASSWORD has a value. URL has a different port than DB_PORT.

Comment: Did it. But it didn't work. :/

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you perform `docker exec app env | grep -e DB_ -e DATABASE`, you will see only

```
DB_PORT=3306
DB_HOST=database
```

This is due to `.env` file [purpose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers#the-env-file). If you want other variables to be set in you container at running stage, just pass them by this way:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:

  # The Application
  app:
...
    environment:
      - DB_CONNECTION=${DB_CONNECTION}
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
```

And now

```
docker exec app env | grep -e DB_ -e DATABASE
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@database:33061/homestead
```

your app container knows how to communicate with your DB

Comment: I have some questions. Should I have the same variables in both .env and yml? I mean, I updated my .env with app_key variable yesterday and in my .yml (#database  env section) should I do the same there?

Comment: `.env` file is kind of setting variables to current compose's environment before executing `.yml` (but differ from prior bash `export` in priority and visibility). It has no direct impact to set of variables that present in resulting image. So you need to set variable in `environment` section, and you can hardcode it directly (as at your listing), or take from `.env`'s environment (as at my one). You can also use a `env_file` option, but it's behaviour is markedly different